# Where is DXGI1_2.h under Windows 7?

Tags: dxgi

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to compile some code under Windows7. But there is an error:

```
Error   44  fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'DXGI1_2.h': No such file or     directory c:\users\administrator\desktop\tightvnc-2.7.7\desktop\wind3d11device.h  33
```

I have installed DirectX, and I don't know which SDK I should install to let VS2008 find DXGI1_2.h.

What should I do to get this DXGI1_2.h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's included in the Windows 8 SDK (in "Include\shared").

Comment: So, How can I fix it? Copy files from Windows8 SDK?

Comment: I think you should install the Win8 SDK and point your project's libraries and headers to it.  You

Answer (score 0):

Need two steps to fix the problem:

1. install Windows 8 SDK under Windows7.
2. use Visual Studio 2010, at least on my computer Visual studio 2008 can't compile the DXGI1_2.h file. But Visual Studio 2010 can!

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed such problem.
1.install windows8 sdk.
2.set the correct paths.
3.some projects can't compiled, such as tightVNC, and then, modify the platform from win32 to x64. then fixed.

good luck.